# Tool for capturing http request and generating c# code

Tags: c#, http, request, network-monitoring

I used a tool once which allowed me to capture http requests, Afterwards it allowed me too generate c# code so I could manually play with the requests and run them again. Does anyone know the name of that tool?

Comment: How can we know which tool you have used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

Comment: I wasn't aware fiddler could generate c# to reproduce the request. It wasn't fiddler but is fiddler capable of it?

Comment: It has the FiddlerScript tab, which isn't exactly what you wanted it sounds like, but I thought maybe that's what you were thinking about.

Comment: There does appear to be an extension, but it looks old: http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code

Comment: I just found what a wanted, it was http://fwptt.sourceforge.net/ BUT your solution is actually better. I wasn't aware of that extension. Thank you!

Comment: PS - I know it's hard to tell, but I'm still actively developing the extension.  I just released 2.1.0.0.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the free tools you may choose Fiddler, but if you need a licensed tool then it is Visual Studio Team System (VSTS) 2008/10.

Comment: Can you elaborate on where VS offers such capturing features?

Comment: Visual Studio Team System includes a WebTest recorder. It cannot capture all request types, however, which is why Fiddler offers a module to export WebTest files.

Comment: Also, you can use the Web Test Recorder to record the HTTP requests only. However, it does not include the images etc. It solely works on HTTP protocol. You may also generate the C# code for the test recorded by you & can also modify it as per your requirements. You can explore the link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182551.aspx